# Unable to convert bytes array into audio AAC file

Tags: java, spring-boot, audio, byte, audio-streaming

I am struggling with finding a solution to write my bytes array to a playable AAC audio file.

From my Flutter.io front-end, I am encoding my `.aac` audio files as a list of UInt8List and sending it to my Spring-Boot server. Then I am able to convert them to a proper bytes array where I then attempt to write it back to a `.aac` file as seen below:

```java
public void writeToAudioFile(ArrayList<Double> audioData) {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];

    Iterator<Double> iterator = audioData.iterator();

    System.out.println(byteArray);

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      // for some reason my list came in as a list of doubles
      // so I am making sure to get these values back to an int
      Integer i = iterator.next().intValue();
      byteArray[i] = i.byteValue();
    }
    try {
      File someFile = new File("test.aac");
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
      fos.write(byteArray);
      fos.flush();
      fos.close();

      System.out.println("File created");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
      System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
```

I am able to write my bytes array back to an audio file, however, it is unplayable. So I am wondering if this approach is possible and If my issue does lie in Java.

I have been doing extraneous research and I think that I need to say that this file is a specific type of media file? Or maybe the encoded audio file is corrupt when reaching my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion loop

```java
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  // for some reason my list came in as a list of doubles
  // so I am making sure to get these values back to an int
  Integer i = iterator.next().intValue();
  byteArray[i] = i.byteValue();
 }
```

gets the value `i` from the iterator, and then tries to write it at the position `i` in the `byteArray`, which kind of jumbles your audio bytes in a weird way.

A working function that converts `List<Double>` to `byte[]` would look something like this

```java
byte[] inputToBytes(List<Double> audioData) {
  byte[] result = new byte[audioData.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < audioData.size(); i++) {
    result[i] = audioData.get(i).byteValue();
  }
  return result;
}
```

then you could use it in the `writeToAudioFile()`:

```java
void writeToAudioFile(ArrayList<Double> audioData) {
  try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.aac")) {
    fos.write(inputToBytes(audioData));
    System.out.println("File created");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
  }
}
```

This certainly produces the playable file if you have the valid bytes in the `audioData`. The contents and the extension should be enough for the OS/player to recognize the format.

If this doesn’t work, I would look into the data received to see if it is correct.